# How to lock application's orientation to portrait for iPhone *only*?

Tags: swift, iphone, ipad, orientation

I know there are some threads relating to this but I also can't figure out my specific case....

I want to lock orientation to portrait for iPhone ONLY (and allow landscape and portrait and no upside down for iPad)....

Tried some code out and pasted this in the view controller, app delegate.swift, and the tableview controller files:

I don't know why it isn't working. I'm trying to use code to apply the changes. I've read multiple threads and cannot figure out my particular case...

Thanks!

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        get {
            if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
            } else {
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.allButUpsideDown //return the value as per the required orientation
            }
        }

    }

    func supportedInterfaceOrientations(for window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
        } else {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.allButUpsideDown //return the value as per the required orientation
        }
    }

    var shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: Bool {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why only through code? Why not put the desired entries in Info,plist and be done?

Comment: BTW - none of this code would belong in the app delegate. There would need to implement the `supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor` delegate method.

Comment: Oh tbh you answered my question with info.plist. Thanks! If you write your comment in the answer section I'll mark it as a correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any code. Simply select the desired interface orientations for the Info.plist.

For your requirement you want the end result to be:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

I you are trying to set portrait mode for iPhone only for a particular controller.I f your viewController is embedded in a navigation controller in storyboard set the navigation controller delegate UINavigationControllerDelegate and add the following method

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations(navigationController: UINavigationController) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

         if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone){
                // Ipad
                 return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait


            }
                    //Ipad
                     return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all //What ever condition you want to set for Ipad.
             }
    }
```